# Kafka - how to send complex value?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have this method

```
  @PutMapping("/{id}/increase")
    @KafkaListener(
            id = "increaseBalanceId",
            topics = "increaseBalanceTopic"
    )
    public ResponseEntity<Long> increaseBalance(
            @PathVariable final Integer id,
            @RequestParam final Long valueForUpdated
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .body(balanceService.increaseBalance(id, valueForUpdated));
    }
```

I try to send message like this:

```
@Override
    public Long decreaseBalance(final Integer id, final Long value) {
        final String msg = String.format(
                "{\"id\": %d, \"valueForUpdated\": \"%d\"}",
                id,
                value
        );
        final ProducerRecord<String, Object> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(
                decreaseBalanceTopic, msg
        );
        kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
        return null;
    }
```

but its not working. How to send multiple message in kafka?

Comment: Your increaseBalance controller method is calling balanceService.increaseBalance not the balanceService.decreaseBalance you're showing.

Comment: I've answered the questions you asked, but you need to be more specific about "its not working" since you appear to have shown the wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

> send multiple message

Call `kafkaTemaplate.send` multiple times.

> send complex value

You can define a producer serializer class to serialize any POJO. Spring-Kafka has a [built-in JSONSerializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#json-serde)

However, I'd recommend you put the ID as the key of the record (IntegetSerializer) and the `value` and the Kafka record value (LongSerializer)

```
final ProducerRecord<Integer, Long> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(decreaseBalanceTopic, id, value);

kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
```